# python count duplicates that are together in a circular list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to count the number of duplicates that are together, keeping in mind that the element in the start of the list is next to the element in the end of list, like a circle. this is what i have now:

```
def test(state):
tests = []
count = 0
temp = []
for x in state:
    tests.append(len(set(x)) == 3)
    if tests[-1]:
        for y in x:
            if y != x[y+1] or y = x[-1]: 
                temp.append(count)
                count = 0
            count+=1

        tests.append(all([temp[x] in [10,9,1] for x in temp])) 
        ##for each list, there can only exist one number with 10 duplicates, one with 9 and one with 1
return tests

print(goal_test([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1]]))
```

Comment: What output do you expect from the `print` statement?

Comment: i expect a list of booleans with all the test results. the final return of that method will eventually be `return all(tests)`, but for now its easier to see which tests are failing